# How can I tell if a function has been used to modify information or not?

Tags: c++

I want to do something like this:

```
class bar{
public:
    bool edit;
    int foo[];


    //If the intention is to change some value in foo:
    float & operator [] (int i){
      edit = true;
      return foo[i];
    }

    //But if I just want to read
    float & operator [] (int i){
        return foo[i];
    }
}
```

I want the right way to do it if it can be done.

The simple solution would be to store two vectors, old and new, and check them each time. But I want an efficient solution without having to manually change "edit" every time I change some value.

Perhaps with r-values and l-values?

EDIT:
The idea is for example, that if I will check the sum of "foo", store the value so I do not have to check foo every time I want to know the sum, only when foo has been modified.

Comment: Write a type that keeps track of modifications. Put those in your array.

Comment: The problem is some parts of the code may pick up the modifiable version but not modify it.  Is defining a Float class with an = operator which flags that it has been modified an option?

Comment: You probably don't want to be returning non-const references to dead values, as using that value is undefined behaviour. You should have the function return reference to the array element type: either `float foo[]; float & operator[]` or `int foo[]; int & operator[]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a proxy object which pretends to be a `float` but has the additional semantics of logging if the value has been changed:

```
#include <cassert>

class bar {
    struct Proxy {
        Proxy(float &f, bool &edit)
            : f{f}
            , edit{edit} {}
        template <class T>
        float &operator=(const T &t) {
            edit = true;
            f = t;
            return f;
        }

        template <class T>
        float &operator+=(const T &t) {
            edit = true;
            f += t;
            return f;
        }

        template <class T>
        auto operator+(const T &t) const {
            return f + t;
        }

        operator float (){
            return f;
        }

        //TODO: add all other relevant operators

        private:
        float &f;
        bool &edit;
    };

    public:
    bool edit{false};
    float foo[42]{};

    //If the intention is to change some value in foo:
    Proxy operator[](int i) {
        return {foo[i], edit};
    }

    //But if I just want to read
    float operator[](int i) const {
        return foo[i];
    }
};

int main() {
    bar b;
    float f = b[0];
    assert(b.edit == false);
    b[0] += f;
    assert(b.edit == true);
}
```

There are some issues, such as all the code required to implement the float operators and some implicit conversions being disabled because we added a user defined conversion and that adding `0` will set the `edit` flag.
Additionally one has to think more about how the operators should be defined than I did for the example to exhibit the correct behavior in edge cases such as `Proxy + Proxy` or interactions with other types.

Answer (score 1):

A function in C++ can be marked `const` to indicate that it should not change information:

```
class bar{
public:
    bool edit;
    int foo[];


    //If the intention is to change some value in foo:
    float & operator [] (int i){
      edit = true;
      return foo[i];
    }

    //But if I just want to read
    float operator [] (int i) const {
        return foo[i];
    }
}
```

Note also that the return type for the `const` function is different -- returning a `float` rather than a `float&` reference. Simply marking the function as `const` does not actually prevent it from changing information in the class. Instead, this function is used for `const` copies or references of the class itself.

Comment: The problem is that the non-const version is chosen even when the float is not modified. You need to have the discipline to use `std::as_const(some_bar)[i]` when not modifying the value, and at that point you might as well have the functions `float &get_editable(i)` and `float get_not_editable(i)`.

Comment: I already thought about that, but I do not think it solves the problem, since on the same copy of "bar" I want to modify and read.

Answer (score 1):

In general, as asked, you can't do what you want - because C++ doesn't allow you to overload on whether the reference is going to be modified or not.  What I suggest is:

```
class bar{
public:
    bool edit;
    int foo[];


    // If I just want to read - use index operator.
    float operator [] (int i) const {
        return foo[i];
    }

    //If the intention is to change some value in foo:
    float & get_ref(int i){
      edit = true;
      return foo[i];
    }
}
```

In other words allow `bar_obj[i]` to get a read-only value, but force the use of `get_ref` to get a modifiable reference.  That still doesn't stop someone writing:

```
std::cout << bar_obj.get_ref(12);
```

when the value returned is not *actually* modified - so don't do that then!

Note that `operator[]` could return `const T&` if your real use case isn't floats.

Answer (score 0):

It is not guaranteed that you actually set a value when you fetch by reference. I would explicitly create a `get` and `set` function to edit the state of a variable:

```
class bar{
public:
    bool edit;
    int foo[];

    float get(int i) { return foo[i]; }
    void set(int i, float v) {
        edit = true;
        foo[i] = v;
    }
}
```

This guarantees that all writes will be reflected by the `edit` variable, which you cannot ensure with your current method (or with other reference suggestions as provided).

Answer (score 0):

You can overload `operator []` on const-ness. [std:: containers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at) do this.

N.B. You probably don't want to be returning non-const references to dead values, as using that value is undefined behaviour.

```
class bar{
public:
    bool edit;
    vector<float> foo; 

    // Mutable float available only to mutable bar's
    float & operator [] (int i){
      edit = true;
      return foo[i];
    }

    // Has to be const float &, as const bar propogates const-ness to it's members
    const float & operator [] (int i) const{
        return foo[i];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a static member as a pseudo-notifier to keep track of function access. Ofcourse you would need to know which function has to be tracked in order to achieve this.

So

```
class bar{
public:
    static int mod_count; //pseudo_notifier
    int foo[];


    //If the intention is to change some value in foo:
    float & operator [] (int i){
      mod_count++;
      return foo[i];
    }

    //But if I just want to read
    float & operator [] (int i){
        return foo[i];
    }

    int getcount()
    {
       return mod_count;
    }

};
bar::mod_count = 0;

int main()
{
  int count = bar::getcount();
  bar mybobj;
  /*
   do whatever operations you plan to do
   myobj[someidx] = 29;

 */
  if(bar::getcount() > count)
   //I know my function has modified the object state  

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use explicit getter and setter methods (and make the data private), instead of overloading the [] operator:

```
class bar
{
    private:
        bool edit;
        int foo[];

    public:
        float get_val(int i) const { return foo[i]; }
        void set_val(int i, float v)
        {
            // Only if new value is different from current value
            if (foo[i] != v)
            {
                edit = true;
                foo[i] = v;
            }
        }
```

That way you ensure that all changes are caught, and there are no false positives for a `set` operation that didn't really change anything (e.g. setting `foo[n]` to the same value it already contains).  And by making your data members private, you prevent anybody from writing code that changes `foo` without `edit` also getting set.